# Volunteers keep leaving

Tags: motivation, volunteering

I've been at a community radio station for a small town for over 5 years and only about 10% are original members from back when I joined. Our volunteers last no longer than a year at best. We are struggling to provide a service currently due to lack of members.

I have recognised poor leadership. Members get zero recognition for the work they do, they arrive, do their work, and leave. What are the best ways to motivate our volunteers who get nothing in monetary values.

**My ideas**

1. Give members an opportunity to obtain copy of their shows; so they walk away with something they have produced. (although some don't like to listen back to themselves)
2. Feedback on shows monthly. This will make our members feel they are recognised but maybe they will feel they are being assessed and under pressure to preform, this might have this negative effect?
3. Membership Handbook outlining the structure of what is required; show planning 30 minutes before, letting us know availability in advance, etc. Currently there is no structure and everyone is given free reign. Although this could be seen as too strict and "school-like" or "work-like"

Any ideas? I'm finding it hard to come up with suggestions that value our volunteers without becoming slightly stricter.

Thanks

Comment: Why are people leaving? Have none of them said anything to give you an indication of why? Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3061/2322

Comment: How about a simple "Thanks for helping tonight, sleep well!"? Just a small indication.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that volunteering has a statistically high turnover rate - people often do it when it suits them, but don't have the luxury of continuing it when their circumstances change or a cash-paying opportunity comes along. There are certainly things you can do to improve the situation, but you WILL have higher turnover than a paying company.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is a question that we can really answer for you, as it is quite specific to your station. However, you know who can answer this? Your volunteers!

Talk to your volunteers, in particular those who have left, and ask them what they are lacking or why they left. You may want to make the feedback anonymous, because with such a high turnover rate, there's a strong chance some of the criticism will be directed at people, not practices. If you really want to improve the state of things, make sure you are actually open to receiving and acting on honest feedback. You might not like, agree with, or be able to do anything about your responses, but you should at least be able to address all of the issues. Explain how you are going to address them, or why you don't plan to.

Answer (score 4):

Why not ask your volunteers why they're leaving?

Create an anonymous survey and send it to the people who have volunteered for the past couple of years.   Ask questions about why they left; what would have motivated them to return; and their overall impressions of the program.  You will get much better results from this approach than from trying to guess their motivations.

Comment: The problem is we can't even get people to respond or to be truthful so we have to guess.

Comment: Have you tried the anonymous approach?  People may be more comfortable speaking off the record.

Comment: @AnotherUser:  If the outgoing volunteers don't respond or aren't truthful then it sounds like they don't trust that the people they talk to will actually correct the issues.  So priority number one is going to be engaging the *new* volunteers with daily "checking in" type talks where you solicit feedback.

Answer (score 3):

To know why people are leaving you have to know why people are volunteering.

Some are in it to:
 - gain experience
 - to help a specific cause
 - to meet a requirement of volunteering for x hours in y months
 - give themselves an outside activity (not their job, and not at their home)

when they have meet their need they will leave. Others will leave becasue it wasn't fun, rewarding, fulfilling...

Each person that starts needs to be be nurtured so they complete their goals, or even better stay around for longer. Knowing why they started will help you understand if you are having turnover problems.

A student looking for volunteer hours is likely to stop volunteering once the requirement is met. If they stay it is a victory. If they don't stay it doesn't mean you have a problem.

You have to decide how many different types of volunteers you need to continue to function in a productive manner.

Answer (score 1):

tt's a community organization. Get some sponsors so that the volunteers get free food and other perks. Join some umbrella non-profit so that they can send some money your way so that you can organize team building activities.

Speaking of team building: your volunteers are more likely to leave if they feel like they are volunteering as individuals or worse, cogs in the machine, than if they feel that they are part of a team - "their team"

If all fails, try potlucks, picnics, soccer games, family outings, etc. Try to make volunteering a chance to network, make friends, meet significant others, etc. Turn volunteering itself into a social event.